# How to take average of number of values greater than some value in array?

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say there are 100 number 1-100, How can I display if 30 % of the numbers are greater than 100?

**Here is the code to check if the value is greater than limit.**

The limit is declared as **70**.

```
public static boolean isGreater(int limit, int[] data){
  for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){
    if (data[k] < limit)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: If you have 100 numbers between 1 and 100, how can any of them be greater than 100?

Comment: Your question is contradicting: 100 number 1-100, How can I display if 30 % of the numbers are greater than 100. There would be only one number which is equal to 100...!!

Comment: No need code, There is no number greater than 100

Comment: Read your question, there is already an answer.

Comment: System.out.println ("false");

Comment: Read your question and please edit it else it will close in a min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int isGreater(int limit, int[] data){
int overLimit = 0; 
      for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){
        if (data[k] > limit) overLimit++;
      }
return (overLimit/data.length)*100;
}
```

By keeping a running calculation of the numbers that are over and under the limit, you can calculate what percentage of the overall list was greater than the limit.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Just got to love how everyone use k++ instead of ++k, which is faster.

Comment: For a small program like this, the difference wouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: @Adder, it's not any faster, look at some assembly and prove yourself wrong.

Comment: @Adder In C/C++ it may be faster, but not java.

Comment: Its use in this case is what makes the speed the same. A compiler worth it's weight in bits will optimize it away. IOW, the assembly code will be identical in C/C++.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the limit is say 70.

Comment: the method should return boolean but he is returning int.

Comment: Because @user3921124 wants a percentage...

Comment: `public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test t= new Test();
        int a[]={0,10,20,30,80,90};
        int b=t.isGreater(70,a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static int isGreater(int limit, int[] data){
        int overLimit = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){
            if (data[k] > limit) {
                overLimit++;
            }
        }
        return (overLimit/data.length)*100;
    }
}
`
When I use overLimit as 0 i get 0 as output and when 70 1200 as output. Why?

Comment: Such a weird error... As soon as I switched the order of operations, it worked. Here's the line that needs to be fixed.
`return (overLimit*100/data.length); `

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int isGreater(int limit, int[] data){
  int counter=0;
  for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){
    if (data[k] > limit)
      counter++
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: Read the question. can you see a real question here?

Comment: I assume 1-100 refers to the index in array, else indeed there is no Q

Comment: You guys fail at the turing test, obviously this is the answer to the question the asker wanted to ask.

Comment: The question is a contradiction, and even if it weren't, it would not be worthy of an answer.